# How to replace image in Bootstrap navbar-brand on scroll with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically my problem is that I'd like to change the navbar-brand image file in my Bootstrap navigation to a different one once you start scrolling through the website. 
The navigation bar is transparent when the website is sitting at the top of the page, but once you start to scroll, the navigation background becomes white. I'd like for the image on the navbar-brand to also change to a different colored one that I have so it remains visible once the navigation background changes.

Anybody got some ideas? Here's the HTML and current jQuery markup I have.

```
    <div class="container">
            <!-- Navbar Header -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Collapse Toggle -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- /.collape-toggle -->

                <!-- Navbar Brand -->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/blockins-logo.png" alt="Logo" draggable="false"></a>
                <!-- /.navbar-brand -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <!-- Navbar Menu -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <!-- Menu -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav justified">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#page-top">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <form class="navbar-form">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Career Opportunities</a>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.menu -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-menu -->
        </div>
    </nav>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Navigation color change 
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 50) {
        $('nav').addClass('transparent');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('transparent').css('color: black');
        $('')
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You could just switch the img src like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var image1 = 'img/blockins-logo.png';
  var image2 = 'img/blockins-logo2.png';
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $('nav').addClass('transparent');
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',image1);
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('transparent').css('color: black');
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',image2);
    }
  });
});
```

Note that you might feel it because the image will load only once you'll scroll down.

another option i can think of is to toggle two html '.navbar-brand' like that:

```
<!-- Navbar Brand -->
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand image1"><img src="img/blockins-logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand image2" style="display:none;"><img src="img/blockins-logo2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
<!-- /.navbar-brand -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $('nav').addClass('transparent');
      $('.image1').show();
      $('.image2').hide();
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('transparent').css('color: black');
      $('.image2').show();
      $('.image1').hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to change `img` `src` with jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        // Navigation color change 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
        var nav_img = $('.navbar-brand img');
        if ($(document).scrollTop() < 50) {
            $('nav').addClass('transparent');
            nav_img.attr("src","first.png");
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('transparent').css('color: black');
            nav_img.attr("src","second.png");
        }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please make sure your divs are properly nested. IN your current structure your nav tag is not mentioned at start but it is closed at end.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {
                $('nav').addClass('transparent');
                $('.brandLogo img').attr("src","img/blockins-logo.png");
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('transparent').css('color: black');
                $('.brandLogo img').attr("src","img2");
            }
        });
```